# How does this php script to create permalink work?

Tags: php, permalinks

I was learning to host a wordpress site in php when I came across this script to create permalinks. I understand that it trims the leading slash and does other several things to parse the gibberish URL into SEO friendly permalink. I want to understand the php script line by line. Any insight?

````
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($root);
$path = '/'.ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],'/');
set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.__DIR__);
if(file_exists($root.$path))
{
  if(is_dir($root.$path) && substr($path,strlen($path) - 1, 1) !== '/')
    $path = rtrim($path,'/').'/index.php';
  if(strpos($path,'.php') === false) return false;
  else {
    chdir(dirname($root.$path));
    require_once $root.$path;
  }
}else include_once 'index.php';```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//**$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** = Directory you're working in

chdir($root); 
//Change Directory

$path = '/'.ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],'/');
//Parsing URI you got from **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** and then getting the **path** from Request URI and then trimming the **/** from start using **ltrim**

set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.__DIR__);
//Getting the include path and setting as current path **__DIR__**

if(file_exists($root.$path)){
//Checking if file exists
  if(is_dir($root.$path) && substr($path,strlen($path) - 1, 1) !== '/')
    $path = rtrim($path,'/').'/index.php';
//Using rtrim to remove any **/** from end... 

  if(strpos($path,'.php') === false) return false; 
//**strpos($haystack,$needle)** if **$path** doesn't have .php in it return false
  else {
    chdir(dirname($root.$path));
//change directory
    require_once $root.$path;
  }
}else{
//If file doesn't exists Include different file
include_once 'index.php';
}
```

Above function isn't worth it for making permalinks and it can be assumed someone use this for scrapped content. Matching `URI` with files and checking if they exists.

Use this Function instead... Cleaner and Easier to understand

```
function sluggify($url)
{
    $url = strtolower($url);//String to lower case
    $url = strip_tags($url);//Remove any kind of tags, leaving the text
    $url = stripslashes($url);//Remove Slashes
    $url = html_entity_decode($url);//Convert entities to characters
    $url = str_replace('\'', '', $url);//replacing any single quotes
    $url = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', $url);//replace characters that is not numbers or alphabets
    $url = trim($url, '-');//remove **-** from start and end
    return $url;//Finally Return
}
```